# css dropdown menu doesn't work on any browser

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a really big headache, with my pure css dropdown menu - it doesn't work on any browser.
The problem is with my second level list (subnav) - when i hover over first level(#n) links, it works just fine and displays subnav, but when i try to hover over that list(list items (links)) it rapidly disappears, and i can't select second level links and navigate.
Here is my [**jsFiddle**.](http://jsfiddle.net/xweDA/)
What should i add to my css, to make it work?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Change top:30px of #n ul

Comment: @SVS, good comment. You should post it as an answer, as it solves the problem. Additionally, OP can remove the top attribute completely, and it would still be displayed correctly.

Comment: @utkai Do u think i should make this a answer just to earn reputation? Actually i write the answer in comments if its really a small issues.

Comment: @SVS, as you wish... As far as I know the purpose of this website is to provide answers to questions into the "Your Answer" -box, and yes, earn reputation as well. But let's just let it be, I at least voted up your comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't have an empty space between the top-link and its submenu. Try to use paddings instead of margins.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses!!!:) @feeela wow...you were right, it was so easy...and why i didn't figured that out...? i just changed #n li margin to bottom padding of 8px and it worked! Thanks!!:)